# Numpy gives different results for almost identical code?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, fuzzywuzzy

```
def match_score(vendor, company):
return max(fuzz.ratio(vendor, company), fuzz.partial_ratio(vendor, company), fuzz.token_sort_ratio(vendor, company))
```

Note: fuzz is from import fuzzywuzzy library

========================

`vendor = 'RED DEER TELUS STORE'`

When I try this code:

```
df['Vendor']=vendor
df['Score'] = np.array(match_score(tuple(df['Vendor']), tuple(df['Company'])))
```

I get this

[image]

However, when I try an almost identical code I get a different 'Score'?

`df['Score'] = np.array(match_score(vendor, tuple(df['Company'])))`

[image]

My logic in #2 is that the vendor is the same across the entire column so no need to put it in a tuple..I can just give it as a string and make the processing faster.

Can anyone explain why passing an entire column where vendor in each cell = 'RED DEER TELUS STORE' gives a different result than just passing 'RED DEER TELUS STORE' to the function as a string? Thanks!

Comment: Please show your `match_score` method

Comment: is fuzz from the fuzzywuzzy library?

Comment: i would assume, that for the first try you are comparing each element of company with vendor. for the second try you probably compare vendor with the full column of company

Comment: I've edited the post to include match_score def but it should be irrelevant because in both cases, what is being passed to the function should be identical. And yes fuzz is from the fuzzywuzzy package

Comment: Please also provide code to create your dataframe. PS: match_score is possibly the most relevant information in your question

Comment: @luigigi that might be the explanation. So you think I should use method #1, right? tuple vs tuple to ensure consistency? instead of string vs. tuple?

Comment: I would think so. But I don't know how the packet works. It was just an assumption. You can debug it and check what values you are comparing

Comment: Why are you using `tuple(df['Vendor'])` instead of `df['Vendor'].to_list()` as suggested in your other question?  At least with numpy arrays, and presumably with Series as well, `to_list` is faster (and cleaner).   Also I don't think you need the `np.array(...)` wrapper to assign a list value to a Series.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm using tuple because according to this <https://learnbatta.com/blog/why-tuple-is-faster-than-list-in-python-22/> it should be more efficient and faster. 
<br>
I did a speed test and the tuple was slightly faster (844 µs vs 827 µs). When multiplied by a million record I think the speed difference could be noticeable.

Comment: Looking at the `fuzzywuzzy` code, I can't see how it processes lists of strings.  The examples just compare two strings.  Have you tried running the `ratio` and `match_score` functions alone, without trying to put the result(s) back into the dataframe?  What do they produce?  Just one value, or a whole list of values?

Comment: @hpaulj you're right. I managed to get it working as per luigigi suggestion but turned out that lamda was actually faster which confirms what you say regarding numpy not necessarily faster than lambda. Thanks.

Comment: At this point, getting the right answer(s) is more important than speed.  No point in trying to do something fast(er), if it gives a meaningless answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tuple` versus `tolist`:

```
In [166]: x=np.arange(10000)                                                    
In [167]: timeit tuple(x)                                                       
1.14 ms ± 26.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [168]: timeit list(x)                                                        
1.12 ms ± 2.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [169]: timeit x.tolist()                                                     
296 µs ± 9.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

or with a series

```
In [170]: ds = pd.Series(x)                                                     
In [171]: timeit tuple(ds)                                                      
1.22 ms ± 1.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [172]: timeit list(ds)                                                       
1.23 ms ± 1.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [173]: timeit ds.to_list()                                                   
394 µs ± 22.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

With a series of string values (object dtype):

```
In [184]: ds = pd.Series(['' for _ in range(1000)])                             
In [185]: ds[:] = vendor                                                        
In [186]: timeit tuple(ds)                                                      
104 µs ± 1.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [187]: timeit ds.to_list()                                                   
27.2 µs ± 179 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As to why you get a difference between passing the Series/tuple versus the string, I think you need to examine the `fuzz` code/docs in more detail.  Maybe even test the function(s) with small examples.  I don't have `fuzz` installed, so can't explore that part of your calculations.

You might even want to make up some lists (or tuples) of strings, and experiment with those.  I don't think this is a `numpy/pandas` issue.  It's a matter of learning to use `fuzz` correctly.